# Convert accented UTF8 codes to characters using PHP

Tags: php, non-ascii-characters

How can i convert string like this

```
%C4%BE%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%A5%C5%BE-%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9
```

to this:

```
ľščťž-ýáíé
```

using PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function, because you have `url encoded` string.

```
$encoded = '%C4%BE%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%A5%C5%BE-%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9';
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);
echo $decoded;
```

outputs:

```
ľščťž-ýáíé
```

Comment: I get output: ÄľĹˇÄŤĹĄĹľ-Ă˝ĂˇĂ­Ă© .. I am using codeigniter 2.2 and if i put this (ľščťž-ýáíé) in url, it auto change on this: (%C4%BE%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%A5%C5%BE-%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9) and urldecode() doesn't work.. I'm not that low, don't worry ;)

Comment: @DanielRosskoRosa Are you using `charset="utf-8"` for html **and** `UTF-8 w/o BOM` for PHP files? You can also try to use `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `urldecode()` function in php. Use the code below

```
<?php
$string = "%C4%BE%C5%A1%C4%8D%C5%A5%C5%BE-%C3%BD%C3%A1%C3%AD%C3%A9";
echo urldecode($string); // Outputs ľščťž-ýáíé
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: look at my comment on Forien answer